# Gurobi has a slower speed than CBC solver (using PuLP)?

Tags: python-3.x, gurobi, pulp, mixed-integer-programming, coin-or-cbc

I have a mixed-integer programming problem set up in python 3.7 using PuLP.
Using the default solver, CBC, my code takes **3.9s**. I want to get this time down so to speed it up I went and got an academic license for Gurobi.
However when I use this as the solver instead it adds nearly a full second on to the run time: **4.7s**, literally the opposite of what I was hoping!

I update this to use the Gurobi solver by adding/updating these lines to the set up (which I assume is correct as it gives the same result):

```
solver = pl.GUROBI_CMD()

prob.solve(solver)
```

Does anyone know what the reason is for the slowness? Are there faster alternatives to PuLP that I should be using for the setup instead if I want to use gurobi?

EDIT:

here are the log files:

1. CBC

```
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 2301 COLUMNS
At line 219058 RHS
At line 221355 BOUNDS
At line 222359 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 2296 rows, 2051 columns and 212512 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Continuous objective value is 0 - 0.03 seconds
Cgl0004I processed model has 1765 rows, 1704 columns (852 integer (852 of which binary)) and 54646 elements
Cbc0038I Initial state - 0 integers unsatisfied sum - 0
Cbc0038I Solution found of 0
Cbc0038I Relaxing continuous gives 0
Cbc0038I Before mini branch and bound, 852 integers at bound fixed and 852 continuous
Cbc0038I Mini branch and bound did not improve solution (0.14 seconds)
Cbc0038I After 0.14 seconds - Feasibility pump exiting with objective of 0 - took 0.01 seconds
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 0 found by feasibility pump after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.15 seconds)
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 0, took 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.15 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost
Cuts at root node changed objective from 0 to 0
Probing was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Gomory was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                -0.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.21
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.21

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.35   (Wallclock seconds):       0.35
```

2. GUROBI

```
Using license file C:\Users\NAME\gurobi.lic
Set parameter LogFile to value gurobi.log

Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.2 build v9.1.2rc0 (win64)
Copyright (c) 2021, Gurobi Optimization, LLC

Read LP format model from file C:\Users\Cian\AppData\Local\Temp\ce8521ad48894665b17cd0db5c63d23b-pulp.lp
Reading time = 0.11 seconds
OBJ: 2264 rows, 2021 columns, 209244 nonzeros
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 2264 rows, 2021 columns and 209244 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xfc10ac4d
Variable types: 1032 continuous, 989 integer (989 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e-03, 3e+04]
  Objective range  [9e-03, 1e+01]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [2e+01, 2e+01]
Found heuristic solution: objective -0.0000000
Presolve removed 616 rows and 434 columns
Presolve time: 0.31s
Presolved: 1648 rows, 1587 columns, 49216 nonzeros
Variable types: 800 continuous, 787 integer (787 binary)

Root relaxation: cutoff, 42 iterations, 0.01 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0     cutoff    0        -0.00000   -0.00000  0.00%     -    0s

Explored 0 nodes (42 simplex iterations) in 0.34 seconds
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 1: -0 
No other solutions better than -0

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective -0.000000000000e+00, best bound -0.000000000000e+00, gap 0.0000%
```

Gurobi was ~0.5 seconds worse than CBC in this run

Comment: If you want specific advice, please post log files from the different solvers.

Comment: thanks, added above

Comment: It looks like a good chunk of Gurobi's runtime was spent in presolve. You could try lowering the presolve parameter value or turning it off completely.

Comment: I don't see where you get 0.5 seconds - both are reporting solve times of 0.35 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using GUROBI_CMD() use GUROBI() which uses gurobi's native interface.

but to be honest the at this size the solve times could be very similar the big differences in solve time will be when they are measured in minutes.

Comment: thanks @Stuart Mitchell , it made it slightly faster than CBC (~0.2 seconds worth). Agree it seems you probably only see material time savings for larger problems than mine.